# Copying entire sheet from master workbook and pasting in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy an entire spreadsheet from master workbook to another workbook (workbook2) everyday. I then need to rename the tab with the current date in workbook 2. I don't want to open workbook 2. I want to automatically hit the macro button on the master workbook to update the other workbook saved in another location.

This is the macro I tried recording

```
Sub Graph()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "04 08 2017"
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
End Sub
```

Comment: You **will** need to open Workbook 2 in order to add something to it. You might consider opening it invisibly, adding the page and then closing it but it will have to be opened.

Comment: Instead of Cut&Paste, You can use worksheet.copy to copy an entire sheet. Anyhow, as CLR said, you have to open the destination workbook (or create a new one) in any case.

Comment: Also, you can copy at the Sheet level, rather than at the cell/range level which would be more efficient. Record a macro where you: Open Workbook 2, then Move/Copy the Sheet from Workbook 1 to Workbook 2, rename the tab and then Close and Save Workbook 2. This will give you the outline code you need which you can then add lines to turn off/on screen updating etc.

Answer (score 2):

As @CLR already mentioned you will need to open a workbook to paste a sheet into it.

Something like the following will work, but note that this is an example only and not a full working solution.

You will still at least need to implement a proper error handling to …

1. catch errors while opening the workbook and it is protected (because already opened by another user) or wrong file/path.
2. catch errors while renaming the worksheet, because the name has to be unique. Re-Using an existing name will throw an error.

Not implementing error handling can result in an undetermined condition if an error is caused.

---

```
Option Explicit 'first line in your module forces correct variable declare.

Public Sub Graph()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Disable screenupdating

    'Open destination workbook
    Dim DestWorkbook As Workbook
    Set DestWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\YourPathHere\Workbook2.xlsx") 

    With DestWorkbook
        'Copy ActiveSheet
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        'Instead of copying the ActiveSheet I recommend to copy a specific sheet by name
        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSourceSheetName").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

        'Rename last sheet (the one we inserted above)
        .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = "04 08 2017"

        'Close and save workbook2
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Enable screenupdating
End Sub
```